# “A system restart is needed to complete the update process” message was shown in KDE Plasma previously but now it's gone. How to enable it back?

Tags: kde, 17.10, plasma

“A system restart is needed to complete the update process” message was shown in KDE Plasma previously but now it's gone. How to enable it back?

Tried installing packages various packages like these:

- software-properties-kde
- software-properties-gtk
- software-center
- plasma-discover
- plasma-discover-updater
- update-notifier-kde
- ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk

But nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required package is `kubuntu-notification-helper`. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-notification-helper
```

Then restart KDE.

### How to verify that notification really works

Run:

```
sudo touch /var/run/reboot-required
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp
```

Notification should be shown almost instantly.